# How to pick a video from the gallery in the google tv application?

Tags: android, gallery, google-tv

I have tried Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT and Intent.ACTION_PICK but it seems that there is no any activity in Google tv to process these intents.

Is there any standard gallery application for Google tv which process these intents?

Comment: There is no standard Video gallery application. There is the Youtube app. Could you describe your usecase in more details..that might help in suggesting alternatives.

Comment: I want to upload video to some external web service from the google tv enabled device.

Comment: sorry I don't completely understand your use case. But sounds like you need to make a custom app for it.

Comment: I need to adopt some android application to run on a Google tv device. It use Intent.ACTION_PICK to run Activity to select video. It successfully run in a tablet, but generate exception in a Google tv emulator.

Comment: Yes, it seems you need to customize that app for Google TV then. If you can send me the code of exactly what Intent you are using, I can help figuring out which app needs to be ported.

Comment: intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);